# UDF input to pass as both range and variant

Tags: input, range, user-defined-functions, variant

I'm using this example to help my understanding of inputs...
In writing a UDF, I want the function to handle both and range as well as individual values, such as: =SurfaceAreaCuboid(A1:A3) and =SurfaceAreaCuboid(A1,A2,A3). How is this done?

```
Function SurfaceAreaCuboid(a, b, c) As Variant
    SurfaceAreaCuboid = 2 * ((a * b) + (a * c) + (b * c))
End Function
```

Would ParamArray work for this?

In this case what is wrong with this:

```
Function SurfaceAreaCuboid(ParamArray r() As Variant) As Variant

    a = r.Value(1)
    b = r.Value(2)
    c = r.Value(3)

SurfaceAreaCuboid = 2 * ((a * b) + (a * c) + (b * c))

End Function
```